# Finding the correct JSON format for Google AI Platform inference

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to run predictions on Googles [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/4) using gclouds ai-platform local predict command. My command looks like so:

`gcloud ai-platform local predict --model-dir=/Users/x/Downloads/universal-sentence-encoder/ --json-instances=instances.json --verbosity debug`

And instances.json looks like so:

`{"inputs": ["Hello World."]}`

I get the following back from gcloud:

`cloud.ml.prediction.prediction_utils.PredictionError: Failed to run the provided model: Exception during running the graph: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1) for Tensor 'serving_default_inputs:0', which has shape '(?,)' (Error code: 2)`

I believe my input format is wrong, but I am failing to find the correct format. Does anyone know how to inspect a saved model to find out its correct input format?

Comment: If you're looking for gcloud formatting: 
1: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict#formatting_instances_as_json_strings
2: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/getting-predictions-xgboost#format_data_for_prediction
For the model, you'll have to look at their code samples for the universal sentence encoder.

Comment: I've read that document, from what I can tell from the signature of the inputs tensor, it should be an array of strings, so I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: Does your input work without using gcloud?

Comment: My input works on TF Hub models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Svetlana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62902852/15305712) is correct. You can batch multiple requests by repeating the line, eg:

```json
{"inputs": "Hello World."}
{"inputs": "Hello Mars."}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to provide a string instead of a list. The following input may work:

```
{"inputs": "Hello World."}
```